# Refactoring starting place for regex

Tags: regex, react-native

I have a function that stripes HTML markup to display inside of a text element.

```
stripChar: function stripChar(string) {
  string = string.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "")
  string = string.trim()
  string = string.replace(/(\n{2,})/gm,"\n\n");
  string = string.replace(/&hellip;/g,"...")
  string = string.replace(/&nbsp;/g,"")
  let changeencode = entities.decode(string);
  return changeencode;
}
```

This has worked great for me, but I have a new requirement and Im struggle to work out where I should start refactoring the code above. I still need to stripe out the above, but I have 2 exceptions;

- List items, `<ul><li>`, I need to handle these so that they still appear as a bullet point
- Hyperlinks, I want to use the react-native-hyperlink, so I need to leave intack the `<a>` for me to handle separately

Whilst the function is great for generalise tag replacement, its less flexible for my needs above.

Comment: Try replacing `.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "")` with `.replace(/<(?!\/?(?:li|ul|a)\b)\/?[^>]+(?:>|$)/g, "")` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/G2Wipy/1)).

Comment: Perfect, that works great, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
stripChar: function stripChar(string) {
  string = string.replace(/&nbsp;|<(?!\/?(?:li|ul|a)\b)\/?[^>]+(?:>|$)/g, "");
  string = string.trim();
  string = string.replace(/\n{2,}/g,"\n\n");
  string = string.replace(/&hellip;/g,"...")
  let changeencode = entities.decode(string);
  return changeencode;
}
```

The main changes:

- `.replace(/&nbsp;/g,"")` is moved to the first `replace`
- The first `replace` is now used with a new regex pattern where the `li`, `ul` and `a` tags are excluded from the matches using a negative lookahead `(?!\/?(?:li|ul|a)\b)`.

See the [updated regex demo here](https://regex101.com/r/G2Wipy/2).